# Making a returned variable from a function accessible within the containing function

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble returning the `dataVariable` so that it can be used by other functions with the self-executing function. `console.log` is spitting out `undefined` right now... Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
(function(){

     var dataVariable;

      function boom(){
        dataVariable = document.querySelectorAll('.className'); 
        return dataVariable;
      }

      console.log(dataVariable);

})();
```

Comment: If you are intending to have `boom` execute, you will need to invoke it, I think if you place the line `boom();` above your `console.log` you'll have the result you expect. You could also do `dataVariable = boom();` but this would be redundant, as you would assigning the value both inside the function as well as when it returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dataVariable is assigned in the boom function, try to execute boom and console log it =), hope this helps.

```
(function(){

  var dataVariable;

  function boom(){
    dataVariable = document.querySelectorAll('.className'); 
    return dataVariable;
  }

  console.log(boom());

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner function would return `dataVariable`. But the outer function isn't set to return anything. Nor are you actually calling the inner `boom ()` function, so it's not executing anyway.

Comment: _outer function isn't set to return_ IIFE can't return until placed in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

A function will declaration will do(return) nothing unless you call it.
   So `var dataVariable ;` ends not initialized hence its value `undefined`

```
  (function(){
    var dataVariable;

   function boom(){
    dataVariable = document.querySelectorAll('.className'); 
    return dataVariable;
  }
  boom();// missing line
  console.log(dataVariable);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke your boom function in order for that code to be executed.

```
(function(){

  function boom(){
    return document.querySelectorAll('.className'); 
  }

  var dataVariable = boom();

  console.log(dataVariable); 
})();
```